# Rank of a matrix with entries $1, \dots, n^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, matrix-rank

Given $n\geq 2$, let $M$ be a matrix with entries $1, \dots, n^2$, e.g.,

$$\begin{alignat*}{1}
A_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
      4 & 5 & 6 \\
      7 & 8 & 9
      \end{pmatrix} & \qquad
A_4 = \begin{pmatrix}
      1  &  2 &  3 & 4 \\
      5  &  6 &  7 & 8 \\
      9  & 10 & 11 & 12\\
      13 & 14 & 15 & 16
      \end{pmatrix}
\end{alignat*}$$

How do I prove that $\operatorname{rank}(M)=2$? I am supposed to use only the elementary row operations. For me, the definition of $\operatorname{rank}$ is number of non-zero rows in a [row-echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form).

For a specific $n$, I can actually perform the row operations and obtain the [row-echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form). However, I don't know how to prove it in general. Should I prove it using induction? How do I proceed with the induction step? The matrices $A_n$ and $A_{n+1}$ are completely different!

By the way, is there any **specific name** for this type of matrices?

Comment: Where does this come from?  A book?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notice that the columns of $A_n$ obey this property:
$$\vec v_n=2\vec v_{n-1} - \vec v_{n-2}$$

This means that only the first two columns are linearly independent, and everything after that can be represented as a linear combination of the the first two columns. Thus, $\rm Col(A)=2=Rank(A)$

Another solution using row reduction:

$R_2-R_1$ of every matrix is a row of $4$'s.

We can replace $R_2$ with $\frac{1}{4}(R_2-R_1)$ to get a row of $1's$. We can then replace every $R_n$ with $n \ge 3$ with $R_n-R_1-kR_2$ where $k$ is the number of $1$'s that need to be subtracted from $R_2-R_1$ to get a row of $0$'s.

Thus, we get the first row of $1,2,3 \ldots$ and the second row of just ones, rows that can't be turned into zeroes, meaning that $\rm Rank(A)=2$.

I do not know what these matrices are called.

Comment: Thanks @D.R., but I am supposed to prove it only using elementary row operations / REF / RREF.

Comment: I added a solution with RREF

Comment: Thanks @D.R. Now the proof is clear to me! By the in your arguments, whenever you say **4**, I presume its $n$. e.g. $R_2-R_1$ is a row of $n$'s.

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: The first solution only proves that the rank is $\le 2$. You need a similar observation to the one you did in the second solution.

Comment: @jjagmath ah, sure. Thanks for the correction. Though I think one can just say that the 2nd column is not a scalar multiple of the 1st column, since comparing the first element the scalar would have to be $2$, and comparing the last element the scalar would have to be $<2$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $n \geq 2$, let ${\bf r}_n := \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & \cdots & n \end{bmatrix}^\top$ and

$$ {\bf A}_n := {\bf 1}_n {\bf r}_n^\top + n \left( {\bf r}_n - {\bf 1}_n \right) {\bf 1}_n^\top = \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} | & | \\ {\bf 1}_n & {\bf r}_n \\ | & | \end{bmatrix}}_{=: {\bf V}_n} \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix} -n & 1 \\ n & 0 \end{bmatrix}}_{=: {\bf M}_n} \begin{bmatrix} | & | \\ {\bf 1}_n & {\bf r}_n \\ | & | \end{bmatrix}^\top = {\bf V}_n  {\bf M}_n {\bf V}_n^\top $$

Thus, $\operatorname{rank} \left( {\bf A}_n  \right) \leq 2$. Since $\operatorname{rank} \left( {\bf V}_n  \right) = 2$ and $\operatorname{rank} \left( {\bf M}_n  \right) = 2$, applying the Sylvester rank inequality *twice*, we conclude that $\operatorname{rank} \left( {\bf A}_n  \right) \geq 2$. Thus, $\color{blue}{\operatorname{rank} \left( {\bf A}_n  \right) = 2}$.

---

**Code**

```
from sympy import *

def A(n):
    r = Matrix([range(1,n+1)]).T
    V = Matrix([[ ones(n,1), r ]])
    M = Matrix([[ -n,  1 ],
                [  n,  0 ]])
    return V * M * V.T

print( (A(5), A(5).rank()) )
```

outputs

```
(Matrix([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
         [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
         [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
         [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
         [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]), 2)
```

---

**Related**

- [Eigenvalues of a sum of rank-one matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/112186/339790)
- [Prove Sylvester rank inequality: $\text{rank}(AB)\ge\text{rank}(A)+\text{rank}(B)-n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/269474/339790)

Comment: Thorough analysis.